# BorderPane not showing the elements added to it

Tags: javafx

I am new to JAVAFX,please help me in correcting below code,as BorderPane is not showing elements added to it.

Do i need to call any method in BORDERPANE class.
Also please give me basic idea on how BorderPane works.
Also let me know if exists any alternative for BorderPane.

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class effects extends Application {
    public void start(Stage s) {

          Group root = new Group();


        VBox vb = new VBox();
        LabeledTextPane ltp1=new LabeledTextPane("abd","ad",Color.BLACK);
        LabeledTextPane ltp2=new LabeledTextPane("abd","ad",Color.BLACK);
        LabeledTextPane ltp3=new LabeledTextPane("abd","ad",Color.BLACK);
        HBox hb1=new HBox();
        HBox hb2=new HBox();
        VBox vb1=new VBox();
        VBox vb2=new VBox();
        GridPane gp=new GridPane();
        hb1.getChildren().addAll(ltp1,ltp2,ltp3);
        Button b = new Button("Change X");
        Button b1 = new Button("Change Y");
        Button b2 = new Button("Change Speed");
        Button b3 = new Button("Race Car");
        Button b4 = new Button("Clear All");
        Button b5 = new Button("Quit");
        hb2.getChildren().addAll(b,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5);
        Slider sl = new Slider(-150, 150, 0); // min, max, initial values
        sl.setMajorTickUnit(75);
        sl.setMinorTickCount(25);
        sl.setShowTickMarks(true);
        sl.setShowTickLabels(true);
        sl.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        Slider Sy = new Slider(-150, 150, 0); // min, max, initial values
        Sy.setMajorTickUnit(75);
        Sy.setMinorTickCount(25);
        Sy.setShowTickMarks(true);
        Sy.setShowTickLabels(true);
        Sy.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        LabeledTextPane ltp4=new LabeledTextPane("Time"," ",Color.BLACK);
        LabeledTextPane ltp5=new LabeledTextPane("Distance"," ",Color.BLACK);

        vb1.getChildren().addAll(sl,Sy,ltp4,ltp5);

        Slider sl2 = new Slider(0, 80, 0); // min, max, initial values
        sl2.setMajorTickUnit(20);
        sl2.setMinorTickCount(5);
        sl2.setShowTickMarks(true);
        sl2.setShowTickLabels(true);
        sl2.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        LabeledTextPane ltp6=new LabeledTextPane("Time"," ",Color.BLACK);
        LabeledTextPane ltp7=new LabeledTextPane("Angle"," ",Color.BLACK);
        LabeledTextPane ltp8=new LabeledTextPane("New X Coordinate"," ",Color.BLACK);
        LabeledTextPane ltp9=new LabeledTextPane("New Y Coordinate"," ",Color.BLACK);

        vb2.getChildren().addAll(sl2,ltp6,ltp7,ltp8,ltp9);



        gp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vb2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane p=new BorderPane();

        p.setTop(hb1);
        p.setBottom(hb2);
        p.setLeft(vb1);
        p.setRight(vb2);
        p.setCenter(gp);
        root.getChildren().add(p);
        vb.getChildren().addAll(hb1,hb2,vb1,vb2,gp);
          Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800, Color.BLACK);
          s.setTitle("Control Play");
          s.setScene(scene);
                s.show();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);
        }

}
```